# I need help to show about Integral Riemann-Stieltjes.

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $\alpha:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing monotonic function, Show that $\alpha \in \textit{R}(\alpha)$ Iff $\alpha$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

My progress is as follows:

Let's suppose $\alpha \in \textit{R}(\alpha)$, so $\forall$  $\epsilon$ > 0 $\exists$ a partition "P", such that:

$$U(\alpha,P,\alpha)-L(\alpha,P,\alpha)<\epsilon$$

I hope you can help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is $R(\alpha)?$

Comment: Do you mean the [Confluent Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/) $\text U(a,b,c)$?

Comment: What are $U$ and $L$? Darboux sums?

Comment: There are a lot of definitions of integration, and the notation varies wildly, so it is nearly impossible to guess what this particular notation means. Help us help you, by telling us what the notation means, or at least what book you are using.

Comment: It’s definitely not that, @TymaGaidash. $U(\alpha,P,\alpha)$ doesn’t make sense since $\alpha$ is a function, not a number.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : While agree that the Question does not reference a confluent hypergeometric function, composition of functions is not prohibited.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is monotonic then the integral of any continuous function exists, so one direction is straightforward. For the other direction, suppose $\alpha$ is monotonic but not continuous at a point. Show that there is a partition which results in $U-L$ being bounded away from zero.

Comment: $R(\alpha)$  means the riemann-stieljes integral with respect to $\alpha$

Comment: hello everyone, sorry that the notation used causes confusion. the book I am using is: Principios de análisis matemático
Rudin, Walter, 1921-
3a. ed.; c1980